# Restricting User Input from Input Box to be alphanumerics and '-'

Tags: vba, excel

How to restrict user input from inputbox to be alphabets, numbers and a character'-'? 
I tried the following code.

```
For I = 1 To Len(UserInput)

    If VBA.Asc(VBA.Mid(UserInput, I, 1)) >= 65 And VBA.Asc(VBA.Mid(UserInput, I, 1)) <= 90 Or VBA.Asc(VBA.Mid(UserInput, I, 1)) >= 0 And VBA.Asc(VBA.Mid(UserInput, I, 1)) <= 9 Or VBA.Asc(VBA.Mid(UserInput, I, 1)) = 45
    Then
         IsNumeric (UserInput)
         UserInput = Cells(Row, 7).Value
     Else
         MsgBox ("Invalid Entry")
     End If
 Next I
```

I see an application defined or object defined error. can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you got the ranges for the ASCII codes incorrect. Numbers are from 48 to 57, small characters are in the range from 65 to 90 and the capital letters range from 97 to 122. The hyphen is correct in your code at 45.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim result As String
Dim UserInput As String

For i = 1 To Len(UserInput)

    If (Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1)) >= 48 And Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1)) <= 57) Or _
        (Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1)) >= 65 And Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1)) <= 90) Or _
        (Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1)) >= 97 And Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1)) <= 122) Or _
        Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1)) = 45 Then
            result = result & Mid(UserInput, i, 1)
     Else
         Debug.Print "Removed invalid character " & Mid(UserInput, i, 1) & " (" & Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1)) & ")"
     End If
Next i

Cells(Row, 7).Formula = result
```

Furthermore, you were missing some parenthesis to ensure that the ranges are (between 48 and 57) or (the next range) or (the next range) or is a hyphen (code 45).

Comment: hello Ralph, thanks for correcting my ASCII codes. But i still need help with this. If User Input is for example like this Mm012-1 only first character gets recognized. How to make the program to see for all characters in Userinput.

Comment: Here is my code :       For i = 1 To Len(UserInput)

   If (Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1)) >= 48 And Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1)) <= 57) And _
       (Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1)) >= 65 And Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1)) <= 90) And _
       (Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1)) >= 97 And Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1)) <= 122) And _
       Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1)) = 45 Then
            result = result & Mid(UserInput, i, 1)
            Cells(Row, 7).Formula = result
          
    Else
    'MsgBox ("Removed invalid character " & Mid(UserInput, i, 1) & " (" & Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1)) & ")")

    End If
    'Loop
 Next i

Comment: You made an error while copying my above code! It should be `(Betwenn 48 And 57) Or (Between 65 And 90) Or (Between 97 And 122) Or = 45`. You need to replace some of the **And** in your code for **Or**. Furthermore, you need to assign `Cells(Row, 7).Formula = result` at the **end** of you code (after the line `Next i`. Then it should work just fine. Look at my above solution again and make sure you copy it correctly.

Comment: Why do you post parts of @Dirk-Reichel answer as a comment to my solution? Do you have a question? If so, shouldn't you ask him the question instead of me (as you are using his code)?

Answer (score 0):

This 2 functions should do everything you need:

---

```
Public Function textCheck(ByVal UserInput As String) As Boolean
  Dim i As Long
  While Len(UserInput)
    Select Case Asc(Left(UserInput, 1))
    Case 45, 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122
      UserInput = Mid(UserInput, 2)
    Case Else
      Exit Function
    End Select
  Wend
  textCheck = True
End Function
```

---

```
Public Function textChange(ByVal UserInput As String) As String
  Dim str As String
  While Len(UserInput)
    Select Case Asc(Left(UserInput, 1))
    Case 45, 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122
      textChange = textChange & Left(UserInput, 1)
    End Select
    UserInput = Mid(UserInput, 2)
  Wend
End Function
```

---

The first one simply returns `true` if there are no "forbitten" characters in the string, else it is `false`.
And the second function returns a string where all "forbitten" characters are deleted.

If you have any questions, just ask (still this code should be easy enough to be readable for everyone) ;)

Comment: @ Dirk Reichel, Thank you very much for your response.  Could you please let me know on how to redirect the process, if  textcheck is false in the first function. I want to make sure that I redirect the user to enter correctly when he makes an invalid entry.

Comment: Depends on what you have. Lets assume you have a textbox and a button. if the button is pressed then check with `if textCheck(textbox.value) then`. the true part is for everything is ok and the `Else` for the case of an invalid input. But as said, to give an useable answer, i need to know how the check is needed (directly on worksheet elements or an userform or whatever)... and if you want it as some kind of conditional formatting, the `WorksheetChange`-event is what you need ;)

Comment: With Dirk's helpful functions you could use a do while loop (separate line at every "~"): with textbox ~ do while not textCheck(.value) ~ msgbox "incorrect entry - type again" ~ .setfocus ~ loop ~ end with.

Comment: Dim i As Long
UserInput = Application.InputBox("Enter Base Product Name")

For i = 1 To Len(UserInput)
Select Case Asc(Mid(UserInput, i, 1))
Case 45, 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122
Case Else
Exit Function
End Select
Next
textCheck = True     . I tried using the Do while loop but ended up getting an automation and error exception occurred error.  Does set focus work with input boxes also? can I use this code like pasted above in my sub routine directly, instead of in a function and then calling it in my sub?. I would like user to get back to 'UserInput' prompt during an invalid entry.

Comment: I am using code below to store it into excel sheet after textcheck=true.
Cells(Row, 7).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = UserInput

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix a small error in my do-while loop. It worked with the below code.

```
Do
  UserInput1 = Application.InputBox("EnterShelf Number")
  For j = 1 To Len(UserInput1)
    Select Case Asc(Mid(UserInput1, j, 1))
    Case 48 To 57
      Cells(Row, 8).Select
      ActiveCell.Formula = UserInput1
      cnt1 = 0
    Case Else
      cnt1 = 1
      MsgBox ("Invalid Entry")
    End Select
  Next
Loop While cnt1 <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) avoids looping character by character.

*test strings*

```
Sub TextVal()
Debug.Print blStrCheck("abcdADDD-129")
Debug.Print blStrCheck("abcdADDD-129")
Debug.Print blStrCheck("123")
Debug.Print blStrCheck("abcdACBC")
Debug.Print blStrCheck("-")
End Sub
```

*function*

```
Function blStrCheck(strIn As String) As Boolean
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
objRegex.ignorecase = True
objRegex.Pattern = "[/d-]"
blStrCheck = objRegex.test(strIn)
End Function
```